# Import Issue for React-Table

Tags: reactjs, import, node-modules, react-table

I am creating a table in react using react-table library. Few days back, I had created a table using the same library and faced no issues. But today I am getting the following error.

**Attempted import error: 'react-table' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactTable').**

Import Statement:
**import ReactTable from 'react-table';**

I created multiple new projects from scratch and installed the node modules.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you add more code here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `react-table-6`

Use this command using Terminal or Command Prompt

```
> npm i react-table-6 --save

import ReactTable from 'react-table-6';

import 'react-table-6/react-table.css';
```

Now it will work

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version of React Table you're using, but looking at the code of the latest version ([here](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/src/index.js)), there is no default export, neither a `ReactTable` export.

It seems that it is now using hooks, so you should use the `useTable` hook to create a table with the latest version (doc [here](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/README.md)).

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem!!!

You have to install

npm install react-table-6

and then import

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import ReactTable from 'react-table-6';

import 'react-table-6/react-table.css';
```

its solved:)
Reference   https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-6

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it in the version 6 way, and installing a later version of react-table.
Based on comment found here: [React table does not contain a default export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796577/react-table-does-not-contain-a-default-export/59811786#59811786), you need to install react-table-6 instead of react-table and replace it as well on your imports.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having this issue on TypeScript install the below package:

```
npm install @types/react-table
```