# React table does not contain a default export

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want to create a table in react using react-table library
version:  `"react-table": "^7.0.0-rc.15"`

When I try this:

```js
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import 'react-table/react-table.css'
```

I get the following error:

> Attempted import error: 'react-table' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactTable').

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Issue for React-Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467778/import-issue-for-react-table)

Answer (score 2):

Try to install react-table-6 [https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-6][1] and use instead react-table. Its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the correct react-table version installed;
This one works for me.

"react-table": "^6.10.3"

Answer (score -1):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/HEAD/docs/installation.md) that's not how you use that library.

You want to import the hooks instead:

```
import {
  useTable,
  useGroupBy,
  useFilters,
  useSortBy,
  useExpanded,
  usePagination,
} from 'react-table'
```