# import error: 'react-table' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactTable')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-table

I have added the react-table library and trying to use it but getting the below error :

```
***import error: 'react-table' does not contain a default export (imported as 'ReactTable').***
```

My code is -

import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

class ReactTableEx extends Component{
    render(){

```
    const data = [{  
        name: 'Ajay',  
        age: 21  
        },{  
        name: 'Shivam',  
        age: 29  
        },{  
        name: 'Vishal',  
        age: 40   
    }]

    const columns = [{  
        Header: 'Name',  
        accessor: 'name'  
    },{  
    Header: 'Age',  
    accessor: 'age'  
    }]  
    return(
        <div>
             <ReactTable  
              data={data}  
              columns={columns}  
              defaultPageSize = {2}  
              pageSizeOptions = {[2,4, 6]}  
          />  
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467778/import-issue-for-react-table,check this link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/basic